# Create observable from polling function

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a function that gets executed at certain intervals with some data. Something similar to a polling function:

```
function poll(handler) {
  setInterval(handler, 1000);  // Mocking network communication
}
```

So I want to use that function in a `redux-observable` *epic* like this (pseudocode to follow):

```
action$
  .filter(...)
  .map((action) => poll)
  .map(results from poll)
```

How can I subscribe to the polling function and use rxjs?

EDIT:

What I've tried but it's failing

```
function start() {
  return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => poll(observer.next));
}


function startProcess(action$) {
  return action$
    .filter((action) => action.type === 'START_PROCESS')
    .map((action) => start())
    .swipWhile((result) => result !== 'proceed')  // I only want to dispatch the next action after we get a `proceed` result from the polling function
    .map(() => ({ type: 'CAN_START_PROCESS' })
}
```

I could wrapp the `poll` function into a promise, and then using `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` but I'd like to do it the reactive way.

Comment: So you want to register to a new polling "looper" for each action?

Comment: basically, I want to listen to the network until I get a `proceed` message. So the redux actions flow would be something like: 

`START_PROCESS` ->
Enter into redux observable epic -> Here we listen to the polling observable until we get proceed ->
`START_PROCESS_SUCCESS`

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest you to do is to write your poll function to return a observable:

```
function createPoll$() {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
    .flatMap(makeRequest);
}
```

And your start process function would look like:

```
function startProcess(action$) {
  return action$
    .filter((action) => action.type === 'START_PROCESS')
    .switchMap(createPoll$)
    .filter(result => result === 'proceed') 
    .map(() => ({ type: 'CAN_START_PROCESS' })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it work binding the observer to itself:

```
function start() {
  return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => poll(observer.next.bind(observer));
}
```

But still don't know if there's a better solution using an already created operator.